# Position of Divs

Tags: html, css

I have this header:

[image]

You can see on the right side a gray rectangule box that its my problem

I have this drop down navigation menu:

[image]

I want to put the drop down navigation menu on the rigth side, next to the buttons and it shows a gray rectangule but not working.

I put the drop down navigation menu inside a div called admin how you can see under:

```
#admin{
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    bottom: 11px;
    right: -170px;
    font: bolder 1.3em 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    width: 125px;
    height: 55px;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Header CSS:

```
#header {
    z-index:1;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF url(../Images/bg.jpg) repeat-x;
    height: 70px;   
}
#header-content {
    width: 760px;
    height:70px;
    margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#header-content h1#logo {
    position: absolute;
    font: bold 45px 'Trebuchet MS', Sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* change the values of left and top to adjust the position of the logo */
    top: -4px;
    left: -2px;
    width: 152px;
}

#header-buttons {
        border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
        }
#header-content li {
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
}
#header-content li a {
    float: left;
    padding: 3px 12px;  
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #272727;
}
#header-content li a:hover {
    background: #01A3EB;
    color: #FFF;
}
#header-content li a#current  {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px -2px #000 inset;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    background: #01A3EB;
    color: #FFF;
}

#header-content h1#logo a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}

#header-content #slogan {
    animation: mymove 3s linear;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 3s linear;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    position: absolute;
    font: bold 12px 'Trebuchet Ms', Sans-serif;
    text-transform: none;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* change the values of left and top to adjust the position of the slogan */
    top: 44px;
    left: 116px;
}

#header-content ul {
    clear: both;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example so that we can re-create the problem.

Comment: Check whatever parent element is around your menu. Does it have position:relative?

Comment: Add a fiddle and your HTML markup.